# Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface javaloader.JavaLoader

Tags: java, coldfusion

Not quote sure why this isn't working on my local. Its working on my remote test environment. Current code:

```
<cfset local = {}>
<cfset local.paths = []>
<cfset local.paths[1] = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar">
<cfset local.javaloader = createObject("component", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(local.paths)>
<cfset jSoupClass = local.javaloader.create( "org.jsoup.Jsoup" )>
```

Its erroring on the `<cfset local.javaloader....>`

Any ideas? the #local# is getting to the correct `jsoup-1.7.2.jar`

**ERROR THROWN on the browser:**

```
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$NoSuchTemplateException: Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface javaloader.JavaLoader.
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getResolvedFile(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1407)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getTemplateFileHelper(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1642)
    at coldfusion.cfc.ComponentProxyFactory.getProxy(ComponentProxyFactory.java:51)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6352)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:6371)
    at cfquote_htmlparser2ecfm1800247286.runPage(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\modules\tools\quote_htmlparser.cfm:8)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:251)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:737)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:573)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:3698)
    at cfquoteadder2ecfm646267101.runPage(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\modules\tools\quoteadder.cfm:24)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:251)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:737)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:573)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:3698)
    at cfmodules2ecfm877363338._factor1(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\modules.cfm:47)
    at cfmodules2ecfm877363338._factor5(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\modules.cfm:45)
    at cfmodules2ecfm877363338._factor9(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\modules.cfm:31)
    at cfmodules2ecfm877363338._factor10(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\modules.cfm:28)
    at cfmodules2ecfm877363338.runPage(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\modules.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:251)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:737)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:573)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:3698)
    at cfbody2ecfm524231656._factor11(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\body.cfm:246)
    at cfbody2ecfm524231656.runPage(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\body.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:251)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:737)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:573)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:3698)
    at cfportal2ecfm1302691009.runPage(C:\Users\Charles\Documents\GitHub\MilestonePortal\MilestonePortalV2\portal.cfm:144)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:251)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:737)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:573)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:505)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:43)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:153)
    at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:60)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:151)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:121)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:536)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:898)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: (Edit) Sounds like it means exactly what it says, ie It cannot find the JavaLoader because the createObject path is incorrect/invalid. Where is that .cfc actually located?

Comment: @Leigh which .cfc are you referring to?

Comment: The custom component, [JavaLoader.cfc](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/). Sounds like that .cfc does not exist where your createObject code says it does.  [This is how CF resolves component paths](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e17.html).

Comment: @Leigh thats a solid point, im not seeing any kind of JavaLoader.cfc. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: (Edit) NP. It is a *not* a core component, so ... if you did not download it separately, then it definitely won't exist :-) BTW, are you using CF10+? If so, like I mentioned below, it is simpler to use [this.javaSettings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually have a CFC named "javaloader.Javaloader"?  That sounds like a Java class to me. Try this:

```
<cfset local = {}>
<cfset local.paths = []>
<cfset local.paths[1] = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "lib\jsoup-1.7.2.jar">
<cfset local.javaloader = createObject("java", "javaloader.JavaLoader").init(local.paths)>
<cfset jSoupClass = local.javaloader.create( "org.jsoup.Jsoup" )>
```

Also remember that Java classes and files names are case sensitive. So you need to match them precisely.

Comment: tried your code, throwing a new different error now 
`Object Instantiation Exception.

Class not found: javaloader.JavaLoader`

Comment: (Edit) @Charles - It is definitely a component, but like Mark said, it sounds like it is not being found on your system - either because you did not [install it](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/) OR possibly you put it in a different location than specified in your `createObject()` call.  Side note, if you are using CF10+ it is simpler to use [`this.javaSettings`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html) instead.

Comment: Definitely a component then. My answer is no good. Do you have a folder titled javaloader containing javaloader.cfc? That's sort of what I would expect from createobject("component","javaloader.javaloader") - or a mapping in cfadmin or your application.cfc file.

Answer (score 1):

The two hints, change in environment and NoSuchTemplateException, suggest that you look at the mappings in the Coldfusion Administrator. You might have omitted the Javaloader mapping or defined it wrongly in the current environment.

Let's assume you are using [Mark Mandel's Javaloader](http://javaloader.riaforge.org/), and that you unzipped it as the folder *javaloader_v1.1*. Then you should define the mapping as:

**Logical path**:
/javaloader

**Directory path**:
{absolute_path_to_folder_javaloader_v1.1}/javaloader/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems with local paths in Application.cfc not being found but working on production servers. I reported it to Adobe this week. A colleague is having the same issue, particularly with relative paths.  CF 11 Update 10.

Try using the full path with // rather than GetDirectoryFromPath to see if it works.

Also, beware of any HTML comment tags (2 dashes) in place of CF comment tags.

Was this ever working on your local?  If so, what changed?